# Need help on this

Tags: vba, excel

I know that there's a post about this topic and I hope you can direct me through it. I would appreciate it.

My problem in the code is Range("AA" & n) = "=CONCATENATE(""S/N"", celctr4,""  is not on contract. Terminated "" , celctr3 , ""."") ". It gives me an error.

Code:

```
Dim celctr3, celctr4 As String
dim n

n = 2
celctr3 = Range("V" & n).Value
celctr4 = Range("O" & n).Value
Do Until n = celctr2
    If celctr3 = "" Then
          n = n + 1
    Else
        Range("AA" & n & ":" & "AC" & n).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("AA" & n) = "=CONCATENATE(""S/N"", celctr4,""  is not on contract. Terminated "" , celctr3 , ""."") "
        Application.Calculate
        n = n + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: What do you mean by `it gives me an error` - what kind of error? The line seems to be a mix of excel-formulas and VBA code which will not work.

Comment: Your header should reflect the problem not like "Need help on this" or "how to do this"...
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry about that. im a newbie in posting to this site. anyway, the error that I have inside the cell is #NAME?

Comment: You haven't declared `celctr2` as a variable or given it a value.  Also, you define `celctr3` outside the loop but check it on each pass within the loop - so either its value should be changing each time (which it isn't), or you just need to check it the once before entering the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line

```
Range("AA" & n) = "=CONCATENATE(""S/N"", celctr4,""  is not on contract. Terminated "" , celctr3 , ""."") "
```

With

```
Range("AA" & n) = "=CONCATENATE(" & """S/N""" & "," & """" & celctr4 & """" _
        & "," & """  is not on contract. Terminated """ & "," & """" _
        & celctr3 & """" & "," & """.""" & ")"
```

Comment: You should use [Range.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx).

Comment: I'm aware that it isn't strictly necessary in this particular instance. It's still better practice to use it consistently - it helps avoid errors like accidentally using `.Value` in a situation where `.Formula` should have been used.

Comment: Quote: "it helps avoid errors like accidentally using .Value in a situation where .Formula should have been used."  No error will occur if you use .value or .formula, so no  need to worry about it.